# Good practice, transfer id or DTO object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, dto

I have a method in the programme that is responsible for downloading messages

```
MessageReceived getMessageReceived(Long messageId,Long userId);
```

at this point in time, it takes one long value. The whole method looks like this

```
@Override
public List<MessageReceived> getMessagesReceived(
        @NotNull @Min(1) Long userId
) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    log.info("Called with userId {}", userId);

    Optional<UserEntity> user = this.userRepository.findByIdAndEnabledTrue(userId);
    user.orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("No user found with id " + userId));

    return this.messageRepository.findByRecipientAndIsVisibleForRecipientTrueOrderByIdDesc(user.get())
            .stream()
            .map(MessageEntity::getReceivedDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

What is better practice: sending the user ID itself or the dto USER object. In the controller I have the possibility to specify the dto object method, but I chose the ID, because it seems to me that it is not necessary to send the whole DTO with additional fields here.  What do you think about it?

Comment: Sure, if you don't need it, don't send it.

Comment: OK. Thanks. And what is the situation with the validation or the message with the given ID belongs to the user about this id. Need to be validated in the controller or in the service?

Comment: I would limit the logic in the controller as much as possible. You could do sanity checks explicitly or with annotations like id >= 1. Then let the service handle an invalid id.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it really matters as long as you are consistent. If you are going to pass the ID here, then you should make a habit of always passing the id instead of the DTO.

My personal preference is to always pass the ID.

Comment: OK. Thanks. And what is the situation with the validation or the message with the given ID belongs to the user about this id. Need to be validated in the controller or in the service?